# Why does a background overlay my rounded corners?

Tags: css, html, rounded-corners

When I use CSS rounded corners, they look like this, and it's great:

http://www.incompetence-central.co.uk/roundedcorners-nobg.png

But if I specify a background color for an element inside them (in this case a simple `<p>` tag), the background color overlays the rounded corners, like so:

http://www.incompetence-central.co.uk/roundedcorners-bgcolor.png

How can I keep my pretty rounded corners without the background color drawing over them? I tried specifying the same rounded corners for the element inside, but if I do that the  background color doesn't completely fill the space:

http://www.incompetence-central.co.uk/roundedcorners-hack.png

Comment: The problem is that your corners are anti-aliased for a white background... while the background isn't white. This is a rather common problem and I'll be glad to hear a solution! (Of course there's CSS3, but that's still not an option. *sigh*)

Comment: I thought rounded corners *were* CSS3?

Comment: Never mind what I said! I thought you were using images. In that case, shame on the browsers with such an incorrect implementation! It does seem to be a bug. (Although I can understand them.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little math may help too, taking border width into account. If your border radius is 5px, and border width is 1px, then the inner element should use border-radius 4px (5px - 1px border). Experiment and see.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll end up going with this solution for now.

Answer (score 3):

Don't specify the background color in an inside element, but just that particular element (with the border).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you set the background colour of the outside element to the same as it's border? That way you won't have the little white space on the corners like you see in your image.

You'll never get it completely perfect, but it is possible to get it as close to perfect so that users just browsing won't see a difference.